# How to use oracle triggers without for each row

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper, eventtrigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER update
AFTER UPDATE OF pos ON table
IF (COUNT (SELECT * FROM table WHERE pos= 'xyz') = 0)
BEGIN
DELETE FROM table WHERE pos = 'abc';
END;
```

Now I want to check the updated table to see if it contains value 'xyz' in the attributeX and if it doesn't, then delete all the tuples which have 'abc' for that column. I'm not sure exactly how to go about this in ORACLE. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is really stretching the use of triggers beyond their natural area of usefulness. You're moving application code into a place where it's going to be hidden from application developers, and quite possibly introducing a deadlock into the code. I'd strongly advise that you use triggers for logging data changes and maybe for enforcement of row change constraints, but very little else.

If your application is PL/SQL based then I'd use an API subprogram to perform the update, and include the code in there. You might need to include DBMS_Lock code to serialise the deletion.

Otherwise, consider wrapping this logic in a transaction in the application layer and running it from there.